Opencart 3.0.3.7 categories don't work on product page
Category links on the product page are not working. It works smoothly on the home page. I am adding screenshots of the homepage and product page. Also, I cannot zoom in on the images and I cannot show additional images. These problems happened after I got support from a developer to speed up my site. I can't reach him either. I need help fix those.
When I hover over it with the cursor, the category section scrolls down.
When I hover over it with the cursor, the category does not scroll, only on product pages.
Additionally, the images do not enlarge on the product page and the image does not change when I click on additional images.
I did my best for months but I couldn't fix these problems.

after checking your website you have a problem with javascript code
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function


Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function

try to turn of these journal theme performance features:
1- JS Combine & Minify
2- JS Defer
